# How to get more tweets by using twitter4j and parse to json?

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I am using twitter4j to retrieve tweets from Twitter. As we know, we can only retrieve tweets less than 7 days. Also we can only get 100 real time tweets. But I want to retrieve more than that. After searching, I found that we can use `setSince` and `setUntil` to get **more than 100 tweets**. But when I used `setSince` and `setUntil`, I still can only get real-time tweets. Besides, I want to know how to parse my tweets to **json format**?
Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws TwitterException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, SQLException 
    {

        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
                .setOAuthConsumerKey("XXX")
                .setOAuthConsumerSecret("XXX")
                .setOAuthAccessToken("XXX")
                .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("XX");
        TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
        Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
        Query query = new Query("KEYWORD");
        query.setCount(100);
        query.setSince("2013-06-27");
        query.setUntil("2013-07-02");
        query.geoCode(new GeoLocation(XXX, XXX), 200, Query.KILOMETERS);
        QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
        System.out.println(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the 1000 most recent tweets in a search, for example, you should use `query.setMaxId()` to the lowest # - 1 from your previous batch. If you are trying to get new(er) tweets since your last query, you should use `query.setSinceId()` to start from the value returned in `result.getMaxId()` from the previous batch.

See [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a query you could use `getUserTimeline(userid, page)`

```
int tweetCount = 250;
long userId = 12312323;  
twitter.getUserTimeline(userId, new Paging(1, tweetCount));
```

Documentation: http://twitter4j.org/oldjavadocs/3.0.0/twitter4j/api/TimelinesResources.html#getUserTimeline%28long,%20twitter4j.Paging%29